# Dynamic Programming. What would be the recurrence relation for this

Tags: iphone, dynamic

There is a frog who can make jumps of length **3,5,7**. There are stones in a river at distances **a1, a2… an**. The other end of the stream is **n** distance away. Can the frog cross the stream. What if the frog can make jumps backwards ?

Now what could be the recurrence relation for this.

Like how can we write **T(n)** in terms of **T(n-1)** and **T(n-2)** and all.

I replied

**`T(n) = min{T(n-1)+3, T(n-2) + 5, T(n-2) + 7)}`**

Is this correct ?

Comment: What is T(n) supposed to represent?

Comment: how to reach to stone an as a combination of jumps from previous stones.